# Unable to flash a Nexus 7[2012][Wifi] with the ANDROID PREVIEW SYSTEM IMAGE

Tags: android, linux, flash, android-5.0-lollipop, nexus-7

I was trying to flash Nexus 7[2012][Wifi] with the  ANDROID PREVIEW SYSTEM IMAGE that is available in

http://developer.android.com/preview/index.html#Start

I follow the instructions step by step, but when i executed "flash-all.sh" it did not work, I got the following messages in my command prompt:

```
sending 'bootloader' (3911 KB)...
OKAY [  0.487s]
writing 'bootloader'...
FAILED (remote: (InvalidState))
finished. total time: 0.715s
rebooting into bootloader...
OKAY [  0.025s]
finished. total time: 0.075s
archive does not contain 'boot.sig'
archive does not contain 'recovery.sig'
archive does not contain 'system.sig'
archive does not contain 'vendor.img'
Creating filesystem with parameters:
    Size: 14569963520
    Block size: 4096
    Blocks per group: 32768
    Inodes per group: 8160
    Inode size: 256
    Journal blocks: 32768
    Label: 
    Blocks: 3557120
    Block groups: 109
    Reserved block group size: 871
Created filesystem with 11/889440 inodes and 97309/3557120 blocks
Creating filesystem with parameters:
    Size: 464519168
    Block size: 4096
    Blocks per group: 32768
    Inodes per group: 7088
    Inode size: 256
    Journal blocks: 1772
    Label: 
    Blocks: 113408
    Block groups: 4
    Reserved block group size: 31
Created filesystem with 11/28352 inodes and 3654/113408 blocks
--------------------------------------------
Bootloader Version...: 4.23
Baseband Version.....: N/A
Serial Number........: 015d49060618000a
--------------------------------------------
checking product...
FAILED

Device product is 'grouper'.
Update requires 'flo'.

finished. total time: 0.168s
```

Comment: The image is for 2013 version of the tablet.

Comment: where can i find image for 2012? atleast kitkat

Answer (score 6):

**This image is only for Nexus 7 [2013] (Wi-Fi).**

Install the last kitkat image for Nexus 7 2012 (Wi-Fi) from here:
https://developers.google.com/android/nexus/images

Comment: I used the "nakasi" for Nexus 7 (Wi-Fi)